# ClassNotFoundException with DexPathList

Tags: android, dex

I have this exception sometimes on my Samsung S3 (4.4 SDK version):

> Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
>   "android.graphics.drawable.Icon" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.xxxx-1.apk", zip file
>   "/data/data/com.xxxx/code_cache/secondary-dexes/com.xxxx-1.apk.classes2.zip"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.xxxx-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>          at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

I followed exactly these elements: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

On my Samsung S5 (6 SDK), there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation; [android.graphics.drawable.Icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Icon.html) was added in API level 23 (Android 6.0 Marshmallow). It does not exist on older devices.

Depending on your needs, [android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/IconCompat.html) could be used instead. It was added in support library 26.0.0, so you need to include `com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.0` or newer (currently the [latest](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html) is 26.0.1) as a dependency, as well as `targetSdkVersion` matching the support library. Support library 26 allows for a minimum SDK level 14.